# How to store file paths in Qt/C++ application

Tags: c++, qt, filepath

I have some configuration XML files in my application. When I finish it, I would like to make it executable. The problem is, how can, and should I, have file paths in my program?

Now I'm using something like this: `QFile file("../DocumentGenerator/data/sender.xml");`

But I know it's not a good approach. Any advice?

Comment: Have a look at QStandardPaths, in particular QStandardPaths::AppConfigLocation and QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstandardpaths.html#StandardLocation-enum

Answer (score 2):

I use QSettings.  I have a section in there which stores the paths used in my app:

```
settings.beginGroup("Paths");
settings.setValue("last_sw_import_path", m_lastSWImportPath );

QString inputFilePath = settings.value("input_file_path", "/home/fpga").toString().trimmed();
settings.setValue("input_file_path", inputFilePath);

QString xmlExportPath = settings.value("xml_export_path", m_appDataPath + "/xmlexport"  ).toString().trimmed();
settings.setValue("xml_export_path", xmlExportPath);

settings.endGroup();
```

And a settings dialog to be able to configure the paths (and other application settings).

QSettings is great - it is cross-platform and just works.  It takes care of the details of where to store the settings for different operating systems.

Comment: So even if I use QSettings as you showed, and add a path to file on Linux (I work on Linux too), but after that, I would like to complie my application to make it executable on Windows, I don't have to worry about paths? I read the docs but still can't understand it how those paths can be cross-platform

Comment: My application is runs on Windows and Linux - I don't change anything related to the paths in settings.  But I do have to set the paths from the settings dialog when the app is installed.  When you use the "/" QSettings handles it on both Windows and Linux, changing it as appropriate.